# Confused. Two square brackets after $_SESSIONS?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Apologies if this is a very simple question.

I was able to put fetch_assoc() results into a sessions variable and then checked using the following:

```
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
$_SESSION['question'][] = ($row);
```

`}var_dump($_SESSION);`

Initially I had `$_SESSION['question'] = $row` instead of `$_SESSION['question'][] = $row` and it didn't work because it only gave the last row.

Out of curiosity, why didn't my initial code work? Why did I need to put in an extra [] after $_SESSION['question'] for it to work?

(Note I didn't include the code for connecting to the database and the query etc for the purpose of keeping the post short since I had no issues with that part of the code)

Many thanks.

Comment: Read about how to [create array elements using the square brackets syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying).

Comment: @axiac thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `while` loop you are constantly assigning a value to your session variable (and therefore overwriting its previous value): `$_SESSION['question'] = $row`. So, at the end of the loop, the value of your session variable just contains the latest `$row` of the loop.

By adding the empty brackets you are telling PHP that your session variable is an array. Now, during every loop, PHP will not replace your session variable with `$row`, but simply add `$row` to the array.

Comment: Just to clarify, I got confused because I thought $_SESSION was already an array because in the php manual (when I looked up $_SESSION) it said that it was "An associative array containing session variables available to the current script."

Comment: @Chug Yes, `$_SESSION` is indeed an array, and you added `question` to it. You have to see `question` as a new variable (within the session array) that can be any type, such as a string, boolean, or... an array. I know all of this may seem confusing, but keep playing around and soon you'll realise the concepts are actually very simple.

Answer (score 0):

First your must add session_start header then you can use session as array

```
@session_start();
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
$_SESSION['question'][] = $row
}
```

or you can use like this

```
@session_start();
$data = [];
while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
$data[] = $row
}
$_SESSION['question'] = $data;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did add a session_start header. I just didn't include it in the question because i wanted to keep it simple.